# Optimizing a "Patch" process

Tags: c#, performance, file, optimization, patch

For some project I need to overwrite Files, but because the user might also edit this file with some other program in the meantime I do not keep the stream often on runtime but save all the data in a byte Array. When saving my program should only save the areas it edited, not the whole file. I have (very poorly) written a routine to do so, but it is expectedly slow and I have no idea how to improve performance here. I'm actually just looping through the whole array, not that smart as it seems:

```
    public Boolean Patch(string path)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        if (fs.Length != this.rawdata.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rawdata.Length; ++i )
        {
            if (br.ReadByte() != rawdata[i])
            {
                fs.Position--;
                bw.Write(rawdata[i]);
            }
        }
        fs.Close();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a recipe for a disaster.  You don't want to save the whole file because the user might be editing it in another program?  The only situation you are handing is if the file size is different.  What if the user changed something in the exact block of code that you are changing?  Answer: you'll overwrite their changes.  Essentially there is zero guarantee that your app will preserve ad hoc changes that the user makes.  What if the user deletes 3 bytes from the start of the file, but appends three on the end?  Then everything is out of sync.

Comment: Your best bet is to just lock that file down and don't let the user edit it outside of your app until the app is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every access you make to the hard-drive (or any other stream), is costly.
Convert your code to use a cached copy of the next `X` (say, 1024) bytes to read, and `Y` (say, 1024) bytes to write.

I didn't exactly understand what your code is supposed to be doing, but say you want to copy a file between streams, your function should be something in the spirit of:

```
private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

void copy(BinaryReader inStream, BinaryWriter outStream)
{
    byte[] cache = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int readCount = 0;
    while ((readCount = inStream.Read(cache, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0)
    {
        outStream.Write(cache, 0, readCount);
    }
}
```

In this example, `BUFFER_SIZE` not be too small (so bulk reading and writing would be efficient), and not too large - overflowing your memory.
In your code example you are reading one byte every time (i.e. `BUFFER_SIZE = 1`), and so this slows your application down.

**EDIT:** Added the code you needed to write:

```
public Boolean Patch(string path)
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 512;

        // VERY IMPORTANT: The throw operation will cause the stream to remain open the function returns.
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            if (fs.Length != this.rawdata.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException();
            byte[] cache = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int readCount = 0, location = 0;
            while ((readCount = br.Read(cache, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0) 
            {
                int changeLength = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < readCount; j++)
                {
                    if (cache[j] != rawdata[j + location])
                    {
                        changeLength++;
                    }
                    else if (changeLength > 0)
                    {
                        fs.Position = location + j - changeLength;
                        bw.Write(rawdata, location + j - changeLength, changeLength);
                        fs.Position = location + j;

                        changeLength = 0;
                    }
                }

                location += readCount;
            } 

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just have to write stuff to specific places, "patching" the file so to say. I guess what you suggested is exactly what BinaryWriter.Write(byte[]) does.

Comment: It would be better if you worked on a cached byte array, and then write it as a whole to the desired location.

Comment: Understand this:
A hard-drive is a block-device, meaning you access a block of its contents at a time. A Memory (Random access memory, or RAM) cell is accessed directly. When you have a normal array, it sits in the computer's memory, and so iterating over each of its elements is elementary and quick. On the other hand, when you have an array on the hard-drive, it is a lot more efficient to load parts of it every time (as big as the memory can handle) and iterate on those. When you load something from the hard-drive, the access to the data is not as quick as the memory's access.

Comment: Would it be an option to copy the Array of Data and access it via MemoryStream then, would that be faster since i'm not writing to the hardware? I get your point now though.

Comment: I've added an example of what you should have written. It might be buggy - I cannot be sure, but I think it does what you meant in the beginning.